# Including newlines in i18n message files in Yesod

Tags: haskell, internationalization, newline, yesod

How can I include newline characters (`\n`) in Yesod i18n message files?

I tried using `\n`, but it gets escaped to `\\n`.

Comment: Just curious: Why would you want newlines to be in the translation? Can't you just use two phrases instead?

Comment: I made an answer, but the more I digged in and tried to test it (I installed shakespeare which should have the essential parts, but I don't want to install something as big as Yesod) the less it worked and the more confused I got, so I deleted it. Although since it was all basically "this won't really be possible at least if you are using it in Hamlet `_{...}`", it maybe wasn't such a good answer.

Comment: @Zeta: How do you handle long messages that need to be translated? For example, canned email messages for forgotten passwords, especially when an enitre paragraph must be phrased differently, depending on the language? Do you load each phrase separately? Makes for a lot of phrases loaded.

Comment: I've typically just used HTML `<br>` tags even in regular gettext / PO files translation strings. Translators should know to leave that alone.